# Can you count the number of VLOOKUP results?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Is there a way to count the number of results provided in a VLOOKUP function? For example:

[image]

If I wanted to count the results for "Cat" above, it should return 2 because only 2 of the entries for Cat have values in column B. I have tried SUMPRODUCT and COUNTIF but neither gave me the results I needed. Any assistance would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or use `COUNTIFS`:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,C1,B:B,"<>")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=COUNTA(IFNA(FILTER(A:A; A:A="cat"; B:B<>"")))
```